# How the two consecutive functions get pushed in stack during recursion

Tags: c, recursion

```
void fun() // say fun original
{
    if(condition)
    {
        fun(); //say fun A
        fun(); //say fun B
        sad();
    }
}
```

when the fun original is called it checks the if condition if it is true, then it called fun A which is recursion.At that time fun B & sad are getting pushed into stack(both functions get suspended during fun A's execution.),after completion of execution of fun A if the condition  fails then the function fun B or sad get popped for execution from stack.I want to know which one is get popped first & the stack structure during suspension.

Comment: usually, a stack is a LIFO DS. you can read more in [here](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/c/lesson16.html), [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_recursion.htm) and [here](http://www.programiz.com/c-programming/c-recursion)

Comment: @SouravGhosh -I am assuming stack like fun B at bottom & sad on top of stack & sad is going to pop first after completion of fun A.Am i right ? correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: is `fun()` always the same function? what does `fun A` mean?

Comment: @thumbmunkeys -I am using fun A for assumption & for making difference between two fun() calls

Comment: @SumeetBajiraoGaikwad one sample sequence can be `original->A->B->sad()`, provided the ` if(condition)` is `FALSE` after very first check.

Answer (score 0):

It's depth first. fun A is followed until it hits the base case (in your case when condition is false), then backtracking doing innermost to outermost fun B. If you draw a picture of this it's a binary tree with same depth between root and leaf.

It's of course the same way you'd expect any function to be called sequentially like ``` funX(); funY()``since you expect every call in ```funX()`to be finished and a value to be calculated before statement`funY()` is evaluated.

Comment: @Sylwester-sir, im assuming that if condition is going to true only once ,at that time A is executing & B & sad were pushed into stack .After completion of A first B popped off & executed,after that sad will. am i right ? if not then correct me please.

Comment: @SumS With conventional computing you have addresses for code in memnory so you push the address to the next expression onto stack before calling a procedure (function). When base case hits you go back to that line. Thus you get to the second `fun()` in the same function. Some languages transform code to [CPS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuation-passing_style) and then you do one computation and pass it to the continuation function which represents the rest of the program.